# RXJS interval won't accept a number value and is throwing a syntax error

Tags: rxjs

Simply trying to use Interval in an RXJS chain which is throwing a syntax error when I try to provide 1000 as the parameter. The same thing happens with Timer and the same thing happens if I remove every operator in the pipe except for interval

```
import { from, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

from(emissionArray)
    .pipe(
      take(emissionArray.length),
      interval(1000), //Error is thrown by interval 
      map((i) => emissionArray[i]),
      toArray()
    )
    .subscribe((values) => console.log(values));
```

Error

Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, unknown>'.
Type 'Observable' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'.

I tried to get the operator working and it's throwing a syntax error. The operator takes a parameter of number which I'm providing and it won't accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interval` is not an operator, it's not meant to be used directly into a pipe.

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to use

- `delay`, to wait xxx ms.
- `switchMap(() => interval(1000))` you want to emit at interval
- something else.

Answer (score 0):

Interval is not an operator it returns an observable, you want to combineLatest the two observables

```
combineLatest(from(emissionArray), interval(1000)).pipe(
  take(([emissionArray]) => emissionArray.length),
  map(([emissionArray, i]) => emissionArray[i])
)
```